# I got a error from i18n aurelia

Tags: json, webpack, internationalization, aurelia

I go through some i18n tutorial but I got error.

This is the error I got

> ERROR in ./src/locales/en-GB_translation.json
>   (./node_modules/bundle-loader?lazy&name=lang-en-GB!./src/locales/en-GB_translation.json)
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while
>   parsing near ‘module.exports = fun…’ You may need an appropriate
>   loader to handle this file type. SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in
>   JSON at position 0 while parsing near ‘module.exports = fun…’

I’m using webpack for this project.

please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added this configuration to my project webpack config

```
{ test: /.json$/i, loader: ‘json-loader’, type: ‘javascript/auto’ },
```

then I install json-loader because I didn't install that package to my project.

Comment: The `type: 'javascript/auto'` property was the missing point in my setup. I just wanted to understand why it makes the compilation succeed.